# useEffect clean up being called on mounting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, unmount

I have a functional component  react version is 17

```
export default function Comp(props){
  .
  .
  .
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {// cleanup
      console.log("Called!")
    }
  }, [...dependiences])

}
```

I have another button that mounts and unmounts the component

for some reason, the clean-up function is getting called on mounting the component

and I can see the console Log

How can I prevent this from happening and call the clean up only if the component is un-mounting

The parent creates the component like this

```
  
export default function Comp(props){
  .
  .
  .
  const [mount, setMount] = useState(false);

  return <> {mount && <Child {...someProps}/>}</>

}
```

Comment: How are you creating the component? What’s its parent?

Comment: @AhmedGaafer please create a minimal example on codesandbox

Comment: ok the app provider is using strict so @tomleb answer is correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using `React 18` and your app is wrapped in the `<StrictMode>` tag, then this is expected behavior added on purpose in the hopes to help devs catch bugs relevant to the lifecycle of their components, such as abusing/misusing the `useEffect` hook.

What the new `StrictMode` actually does is unmount and then remount every component once it gets rendered.

Resulting in an initial lifecycle that looks like this:

```
* React mounts the component.
  * Layout effects are created.
  * Effects are created.
* React simulates unmounting the component.
  * Layout effects are destroyed.
  * Effects are destroyed.
* React simulates mounting the component with the previous state.
  * Layout effects are created.
  * Effects are created.
```

Note that it only behaves this way in dev environment, and not in the production build.

**ref:** https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-strict-mode-behaviors